# Cannot add a rule to Azure topic subscription

Tags: azure, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

It's a very basic scenario and I don't know why it does not work.. I cannot add a rule to a topic.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(
            nsConnString,
            topicName,
            subsName,
            ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

        subscriptionClient.AddRuleAsync(new RuleDescription
        {
            Filter = new CorrelationFilter { Label = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        }).Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

AddRuleAsync call always throws - "The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation.". The service bus was created using MS Getting started section. I am using 0.0.7-preview package with .NET Core. I can send and receive messages using topics I create, I just cannot add rules for some reason.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Raise an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues to get the team to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue  that you mentioned with  0.0.7-preview package. Please have a try to use lastest [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 1.0.0-RC1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/1.0.0-RC1) version. It works correctly on my side.

[image]

Comment: Whoa, didn't know about that library! What's the point for Microsoft in maintaining 2 libraries covering same functionality?

Comment: It seems that it is an issue in 0.0.7-preview, but it is fixed in the latest version.

Comment: Yes, it's the same library)). I need to get more sleep)